# DotNetNuke how to add Tab programmatically with null parentId

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

With below codes I can add new Tabs in DotNetNuke with **TabController** class.
**TabController.AddTab(...)** method takes a **TabInfo** object.
My problem is I want to set the **ParentId** of the new tabInfo to **null**, but its not nullable int.
here is my code:

```
TabInfo newTab=new TabInfo();
newTab.PortalId=PortalId;
newTab.Title="some title";
/*...*/
newTab.ParentId=0 /*--here is my problem--*/

TabController controller = new TabController();
controller.AddTab(newTab);
```

If the **ParentId** doesn't exists, It causes a Foreign key error...
How can I set the tab's ParentId to null?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set the **ParentID** to a page that I'm sure exists...
After that, with below script I set the **ParentID** of the new tab to **null**

```
TabInfo tab;
tab=new TabInfo()
//set properties of tab object...
//..
tab.ParentId = 38;//38 is my main page tabID
//...
//add new tab code
tabid = controller.AddTab(tab);
//update parentID code
DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.Instance().ExecuteSQL("update tabs set parentid=null where tabid=" + tabid);
```

**EDIT:**
Based on [*Javier*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261813/javier) answer int the comments the result is like this:

```
tab.ParentId = DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Null.NullInteger;
```

Comment: you should set ParentId to DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Null.NullInteger, is a DNN Constant (-1), that is normally used with you want null value.